# Why one can set TFS predefined variables when they are said to be read-only?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, vnext

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=tfs-2018

> These variables are automatically set by the system and read-only. (The exceptions are Build.Clean and System.Debug.)

Nonetheless, if one tries to create a vnext build with the following tasks

1. Inline Powershell - `Write-Host $env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION`
2. Inline Powershell - `Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=build.sourceversion;]"+'someNewValue')`
3. Inline Powershell - `Write-Host $env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION`

Task 2 won't fail, and the last task will output something like

> 2018-10-24T07:37:23.1232438Z someNewValue

instead of the expected original source version (the value printed in the first task).

So,

1. Either I am misreading the docs / they are unclear on that account
2. Or is it some genuine defect in TFS that one should pursue with MS?

Comment: One of my colleagues said it is by design. For example this way you can overwrite the build name. You should ask Microsoft for clearance instead, but I think the docs are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's expected behavior.

The predefined variables are automatically set by the system and read-only.

> However if you have defined a pipeline variable of the **same name**
>   as an environment variable (for example, `PATH`), your pipeline variable
>   value overrides the agent host's environment variable.

See [Environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=vsts&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables) for details.

So, in your scenario actually you defined a new pipeline variable with the same name as the pre-defined one, but not really overwrite the predefined variable. And they can only be used in the pipelines...

---

**UPDATE:**

Well, the documentation is somewhat misleading about the `Environment Variables` and makes some slightly contradictory claims about their readonlyness. Actually all variables (*predefined, build, environment...) basically work as the environment variables [mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=vsts&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables).

BTW, you can get all the available environment variables by `get-childitem -path env:*` in pipeline.*

PowerShell script for example:

```
$environmentVars = get-childitem -path env:*
foreach($var in $environmentVars)
{
 $keyname = $var.Key
 $keyvalue = $var.Value

 Write-Output "${keyname}: $keyvalue"
}
```

Comment: That's what I think is probably is the case here. But the problem is that the [section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=tfs-2018&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables) you've quoted here deals with **Environment** variables (as OS environment, not the build/agent environment). So the documentation is not clear on that point. Well, it's even worse actually - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=tfs-2018&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#system-defined-variables  `As a pipeline author or end user, you cannot set...`

Comment: Well, actually it includes the OS and build/agent environment variables. Basically you can get all the environments variables by `get-childitem -path env:*` in pipeline.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the case... Just that the documentation is at least moderately misleading. I'll accept this answer if you mention something like `all variables (predefined, build, environment...) basically work as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=tfs-2018&tabs=yaml%2Cpowershell#environment-variables ,despite that the documentation makes some slightly contradictory claims about their readonlyness and etc.` - you probably don't object to the correctness of that statement, do you?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/readonly-variables.md  - we are on Version Dev18.M170.6 and we can't change readonly variables anymore in the build agents.